# Why does vector $v$ follow the uniform law on the unit sphere in $R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(A_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be a random symmetric matrix of centered Gaussian random variables such that
$$
E[A_{ij}^2]=1/n, \,  E[A_{ii}^2]=2/n
$$
Assume that $A=G^* DG$ where the orthogonal matrix $G$ follows the uniform law on the sphere, $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and also $G$ and $D$ are independent.

Let $\mathbf{1}$ be a $n-$dimensional vector $(1,\dots, 1)$ and $v:=n^{-1/2}G\mathbf{1}$.

Why does vector $v$ follow the uniform law on the unit sphere in $R^n$?

---

It is enough to show that the norm of $v$ is equal to 1, that is,
$$
\|v\|^2=n^{-1}\|G\mathbf{1}\|^2
$$
Is this one equal to 1?

For example, if let $G=[u_1,\dots, u_n]$ where $u_i$ are the corresponding eigenvectors with $\|u_i\|^2=1$